# How to insert Identity Server 4 persisted ApiSecret values using T-SQL

Tags: c#, hash, identityserver4

I have been through the Identity Server 4 QuickStart for using Entity Framework for persistent storage of configuration and operational data. In the QuickStart, the ApiResources are loaded into the database in code. The Api secret is set with

```
        new ApiResource("api1", "My API")
        {
            ApiSecrets = { new Secret("secret".Sha256())}
        }
```

in the ApiResource constructor. When, in Startup.InitializeDatabase, that ApiResource is added to the ConfigurationDbContext.ApiResources DbSet,

```
        foreach(var resource in Config.GetApiResources())
        {
            context.ApiResources.Add(resource.ToEntity());
        }
        context.SaveChanges();
```

the record in the child ApiSecrets table contains a readable text value in the ApiSecrets.Value field.

```
    K7gNU3sdo+OL0wNhqoVWhr3g6s1xYv72ol/pe/Unols=
```

I would like to manage my configuration data through SQL scripts, but I can't figure out how to set the ApiSecrets.Value correctly. I've tried using T-SQL HASHBYTES('SHA2_256', 'secret'), but that produces an unreadable (I think binary) value in ApiSecrets.Value. Is there a way to set the hashed secret correctly through T-SQL?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You were on the right track to use `HASHBYTES`, just need to get the `Base64` hash out of the `BinaryHash`:

```
DECLARE @HASHBYTES VARBINARY(128) = hashbytes('sha2_256', 'secret')
SELECT cast(N'' as xml).value('xs:base64Binary(sql:variable("@HASHBYTES"))', 'varchar(128)');
```

Answer (score 2):

Hope this would help.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[ConvertToSha256ForIdentityServer](@secret varchar(128))
RETURNS varchar(128) AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @HASHBYTES VARBINARY(128) = hashbytes('sha2_256', @secret)
    RETURN (SELECT top 1 cast(N'' as xml).value('xs:base64Binary(sql:variable("@HASHBYTES"))', 'varchar(128)'));
END
```

to insert

```
MERGE INTO dbo.[ClientSecrets] AS TARGET
USING (
        VALUES
         (dbo.ConvertToSha256ForIdentityServer('mysecret'),'SharedSecret',getdate(),1)
      )
      AS Source ([Value],[Type],[Created],[ClientId])
ON Target.[ClientId] = source.[ClientId]
WHEN matched THEN
  UPDATE SET
      [Value] = Source.[Value],
      [Type] = Source.[Type]

WHEN NOT matched BY target THEN
  INSERT ([Value],[Type],[Created],[ClientId])
  VALUES ([Value],[Type],[Created],[ClientId]);
```

Comment: Notice that this and [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54207758/23118) produces different result! This `ConvertToSha256ForIdentityServer` function generated values that matched the existing entries in the `ApiSecrets` table, so from my perspective this is the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the algorithm below to create secret, then you can store it in SQL:

```
using System.Security.Cryptography;

static class Extentions
{

    public static string Sha256(this string input)
    {
        using (SHA256 shA256 = SHA256.Create())
        {
            byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input);
            return Convert.ToBase64String(((HashAlgorithm)shA256).ComputeHash(bytes));
        }
    }
}


void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine( "secret-as-guid".Sha256());
}
```

you can also use [passwordgenerator.net](https://passwordsgenerator.net/sha256-hash-generator/)