# Declare variable for HashBytes

Tags: sql, sql-server-2017, declare, hashbytes

I am following a simple example from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54207257/how-to-insert-identity-server-4-persisted-apisecret-values-using-t-sql):

```
DECLARE @HASHBYTES VARBINARY(128) = hashbytes('sha2_256', 'secret')
SELECT cast(N'' as xml).value('xs:base64Binary(sql:variable("@HASHBYTES"))', 'varchar(128)');
```

It returns a correct hashed value: `K7gNU3sdo+OL0wNhqoVWhr3g6s1xYv72ol/pe/Unols=`

Now I tried to declare secret as a variable following Microsoft Hashbytes documentation [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/hashbytes-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#return-the-hash-of-a-variable):

```
DECLARE @HashThis nvarchar(32);  
SET @HashThis = CONVERT(nvarchar(32),'secret');
DECLARE @HASHBYTES VARBINARY(128) = hashbytes('sha2_256', @HashThis)
SELECT cast(N'' as xml).value('xs:base64Binary(sql:variable("@HASHBYTES"))', 'varchar(128)');
```

it returns a wrong hash:

```
s6jeuSg7FUrj9WBqMj0GbSRudEDi2NTJqHqmG5UYOiY=
```

Is there any way to declare a secret as a variable to get the correct hash?

I am new to this Hashbytes stuff in SQL. I am using it on SQL Server 2017.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you are using `nvarchar` to declare your secret. but it should be `varchar` and it would solve the problem.

So let's test it:

```
DECLARE @HashThis varchar(32);  
SET @HashThis = CONVERT(varchar(32),'secret');
DECLARE @HASHBYTES VARBINARY(128) = hashbytes('sha2_256', @HashThis)
SELECT cast(N'' as xml).value('xs:base64Binary(sql:variable("@HASHBYTES"))', 'varchar(128)');
```

Will return what you expected initially:

```
K7gNU3sdo+OL0wNhqoVWhr3g6s1xYv72ol/pe/Unols=
```

By the way, you do not need to CONVERT, you can pass the secret as varchar. something like:

```
DECLARE @HashThis varchar(32);
SET @HashThis = 'secret';
```